# how do I know if my camera can accept wireless remote shutter control?

Tags: remote

I looked everywhere and cannot seem to be able to find any information. I have Olympus EPM2 micro 4/3 format. I use it semi-professionally for casual portraits and now I want  to use it to take pictures of myself wearing jewellery pieces that I make. So I need the remote shutter control. There is one with a cord for this model but I don't think the cord will be long enough.

How do I know if my camera is capable of working with a cordless shutter control? How do I know if a camera is capable to do that in general? I looked at the bunch of wireless remote models and the since my camera is older, I don't see it listed anywhere.

And otherwise, what are my options for this kind of a project?

Comment: Poor mans shutter release: 10s timer mode.

Comment: I tried that, I can't seem to get into a good position and relax in 10 seconds.  That's what I am doing now until I figure out the shutter thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual procedure is to look up the official product name of a wired remote in your camera handbook, then search on an auction platform with that product name for a wireless product.

Typical generic remotes employ a 2.5mm TRS connector, and the cables from those connectors to various cameras are often available separately.

There are both wireless flash triggers that can also double as wireless shutter controls as well as dedicated shutter remotes for wireless and/or timelapse use.

Comment: that was useful, thank you. The official wired remote is RM-UC1 and I searched eBay for "RM-UC1 wireless", and I see a product from Hong Kong that seems to do the job. On the pricey side, but I will continue to reseach

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that camera specifically, but a lot of the cheap [but perfectly serviceable] remotes have interchangeable plugs on the end.

You can therefore insert another long cable & extend the length quite easily.

[example from eBay UK](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/UC1-Timer-Remote-Extension-Cable-for-Olympus-EP3-EPL1-EPM2-EM5-E620-E520-E410/321887683356?epid=26013771517&hash=item4af200431c:g:MR8AAOSwI-BWFlb1)
If it has that 'headphone jack' type adaptor, then it can be extended.

Image with logo removed, for if the eBay link goes stale

[image]

Comment: ok, so I buy a generic timer with a long cord and an adapter for Olympus? Did I get that correctly?

Comment: You get a generic remote/timer, one with one of those plugs in the middle. Then you buy a remote extension, long as you like. [example eBay search](https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_odkw=camera+remote+extension&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=shutter+release+extension&_sacat=0) (& the extension doesn't matter what camera it says it's for, so long as it has that mini-jack at each end)

Answer (score 0):

I'd look up the user manual you've bought it with or google up the manual for the sepcific model. You are about to find whether it can use wireless remote shutter and what models. New cameras with WiFi/bluetooth can be operated from your phone/tablet app as well.

Some shutter remotes use 2.5 mm jack, also known as 2.5 stereo jack providing 3 terminals - AF trigger, shutter trigger and common. You can use 2.5mm jack male-female cable to enhance the range or build your own.

There is also a possibility to get wireless reciever that is connected to the 2.5mm jack as well. It may have more than one output to allow for synchronised multiple units trigger, like cameras and flashes.